# 'Leaked window error' warning on a device orientation change while Options Menu is open (API 23,24,25)

Tags: android, android-activity

The following warning message arises on API 23, 24 or 25 devices on device orientation changes from Portrait to Landscape (and vice versa) while the the Settings (options menu) is open. In both cases I have this error message in my log:

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.example.test.myapplication.MainActivity has leaked window
>   android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{6bb10b1 V.E...... ......ID
>   0,0-686,168} that was originally added here
>                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
>                            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
>                            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>                            at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1258)
>                            at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1110)
>                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:105)
>                            at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompatKitKat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompatKitKat.java:30)
>                            at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat$KitKatPopupWindowImpl.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:129)
>                            at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:206)
>                            at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:722)
>                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:160)
>                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
>                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
>                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
>                            at
>   ...

I saw some questions here, on SO, but it seems to me that everyone just took the workaround and have overridden `onStop()` or `onBackPressed()` in main activity.

To test and debug, I have created a simple project with the AS wizard (with Navigation Drawer Activity option activated, so there is an Options Menu already incorporated). The only thing added/changed was:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in the `manifest` file, but I am still having the same warning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added   goto this link it may help you.

Comment: The answers are for a project with some code in it. I consider that a project created with the wizard with no changes and with a simple use as open a menu and turn the device should not produce an error. I am thinking more of a bug.

Comment: <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">  add it in your amnifest

Comment: Added android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in the manifest file , but still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug. I reported and it had been since fixed by Google. It can be followed [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/37072551?pli=1)

Comment: It seems the didnt fix it. I still get this in API 23,25,27 in both emulator and real device

Comment: That's strange... Could it be a regression? I didn't check for a while, but at the time I posted this, it was fixed for my apps

Comment: I dont know either. I posted my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419585/activity-has-leaked-window-android-widget-popupwindow-api-27?noredirect=1#comment91783979_52419585. You can check it again and let me know

Comment: Mine still works, but I return true in onCreateOptionsMenu()

Comment: I also tried that, but nothing. I did the simplest thing. Create a new project with basic activity. Run it, open the menu and rotate. I mean its all generic code nothing custom.

Comment: I did the same when debugging mine. It's just after trying that that I reported the bug... Have you tried restarting the emulator or reinstalling? I know it's trivial but who knows

Comment: The thing is, that happens in my real device too with oreo android. So i dont think its the emulator. I will give it a try though

Comment: Yes, could be an other option for debugging to test in the emulator :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
  android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
```