# Activity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow API 27

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple Activity with a inflated popup menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

When i open the menu and rotate i get the following error:

**Activity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow**

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity    com.ehr.CompanyActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{f8c5b6f V.E...... ......ID 0,0-515,504} that was originally added here at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:485) at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346) at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93) at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1433) at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1284) at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:76) at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat$PopupWindowCompatApi19Impl.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:115) at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:219) at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:733) at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:176) at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:203) at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:289) at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:176) at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:805) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)

Its pretty much a generic code i didnt wrote anything more.

Comment: where is `return` in your  `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: @NileshRathod i updated it

Comment: Can u share whole activity code and whole `error` with question

Comment: @NileshRathod i edited it

Comment: you have to try this `return true`

Comment: I too got this same error the other day (on Nougat). If you want, you can handle this case in onDestroy()

Comment: @RahulKumar Please elaborate.

Comment: adding invalidateoptionsmenu() in onDestroy of activity might do the trick. Not sure though.

Comment: @RahulKumar not working either

Comment: facing same problem,.

Comment: For a custom PopupWindow, this Q&A helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055479/popupmenu-popupwindowpopupviewcontainer-leak

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have inflated the menu but still, you are returning the `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`. Change return value as `true`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

     return true;
}
```